# buynow works with paypal user but not credit card only

Tags: paypal

New to the wonderful world of paypal payments.

I have a simple button which works great on my merchant account when the user is a paypal user.  However, when a credit card only payment is submitted, I get:

```
We're sorry, but we can't send your payment right now
We are not able to process your payment using your PayPal account at this time. 
Please return to the merchant's website and try using a different payment method (if available).
```

I have triple checked that the merchant account has the "Accept non paypal payments" checked.  The merchant account was setup about two weeks ago.  It is a business account (as opposed to a business pro account).  I have checked and rechecked the rest of the options over and over.  I use a new chrome incognito window for each test to avoid cookie/session issues.

I have tested using the sandbox.  Credit card only works fine.

My button code looks like:

```
<script 
    data-tax="0" 
data-shipping="0" 
data-amount="5.50" 
data-quantity="1" 
data-name="Team Reg U15 Boys Intergraph"
data-button="buynow" 
src="/nafutsal/bundles/ceradteam/js/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=KDTT4D89UN6DN"
    ></script>
```

The amount is small for testing but I didn't see an actual min limit anywhere.

Any idea why credit card only payments do not work in production?

Comment: Is the merchant account verified by paypal?

Comment: Pretty sure.  They deposited a token amount and I verified it.  Is there a specific link I should look at?  Seems like the screens are always changing and so much of the stuff online no longer matches the current application.

Comment: You may try calling paypal and talking with them over the phone to figure this out. I don't think this is an issue with your code, but something tells me it is probably their side.

Comment: Why would someone do a drive by down vote on a two and half year old answered question?  Is that you Donald Trump?

Answer (score 2):

Ok.  So I had a long conversation with paypal support.  The credit card transaction was failing because I was using one computer for both sandbox testing and production testing.  Using an incognito browser window was not enough.

I'm sure this is all documented somewhere.